# ArcGIS Runtime : How to determine the relationship between two 3D geometry

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I want to judge the relationship between two 3D geometry:

1. Whether overlap
2. If overlap, what is the overlapped part and what is the overlapped volume.

I want to know if there is a mature method in ArcGIS to achieve such a function, because it is too difficult for me to implement specific mathematical problems.

Currently I found a related class `GeometryEngine` in ArcGIS, but it seems to be invalid:

```
var onMapLocation = new MapPoint(0, 0, 0, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);

var num = 1;
List<MapPoint> points = new List<MapPoint>();

points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X, onMapLocation.Y + num, onMapLocation.Z + num, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X + num, onMapLocation.Y + num, onMapLocation.Z + num, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X + num, onMapLocation.Y, onMapLocation.Z + num, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X, onMapLocation.Y, onMapLocation.Z + num, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));

Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Polygon polygon1 = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Polygon(points);

var num2 = 2;
points = new List<MapPoint>();
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X, onMapLocation.Y + num2, onMapLocation.Z + num2, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X + num2, onMapLocation.Y + num2, onMapLocation.Z + num2, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X + num2, onMapLocation.Y, onMapLocation.Z + num2, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));
points.Add(new MapPoint(onMapLocation.X, onMapLocation.Y, onMapLocation.Z + num2, onMapLocation.SpatialReference));

Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Polygon polygon2 = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Polygon(points);

var g1 = GeometryEngine.Difference(polygon1, polygon2);
```

The result g1 is empty.

Here is the reference:

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_Difference.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong method, the correct method are as follows:

```
var b = GeometryEngine.Intersects(polygon1, polygon2);
var g3 = GeometryEngine.Intersection(polygon1, polygon2);
var g2 = GeometryEngine.Intersections(polygon1, polygon2);
```

```
public static bool Intersects(Geometry geometry1, Geometry geometry2);
public static Geometry? Intersection(Geometry geometry1, Geometry geometry2);
public static IReadOnlyList<Geometry> Intersections(Geometry geometry1, Geometry geometry2);
```